# Reload url information jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this jquery code imagine that the code inside just load a drop-down menu with all the information from the xml.

In my html file I have a `<script>` that when I press a button it changes some values inside the .xml file. When I change the option in the radio button it uses the information loaded when I first entered the page.

How can I do to make the Ajax code reload that information since it is different than when it took the info?

```js
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://example.xml',
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    success: function(data){
    $('input[type=radio][name=action]').change(function() {



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Update Interface</title>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "Interface.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel=stylesheet href="//codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
        <script src="//codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script src="//codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/vkiryukhin/vkBeautify/master/vkbeautify.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body class="mt-2 px-2">
        <h3 class="text-danger">Form Interface for POST, PUT & DELETE</h3>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="PUT" name="action" value="PUT">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">PUT</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="POST" name="action" value="POST">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">POST</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="DEL" name="action" value="DEL">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">DEL</label>
              </div><br>
              <select name="codes" id="codes"></select></br>
            <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <label for="response">XML Response:</label><br>
        <textarea id="response" name="response" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise to provide more information. Show us some HTML.

Comment: If you are having a cache problem that the updated xml file isn't showing after you have edited it than you may need to change the URL with a random variable like `\`http://example.xml?n=${Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER/Math.random()}\`` to ensure it doesn't get cached.